# Triying to make a chronometer on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm triying to make a chronometer on Android with timer and the sheduleAtFixedRate method, but it looks like calling my textview inside the run method of the timer is making my application stop. What I'm I doing wrong? here's my code:

```
Button boton_iniciar;
TextView texto_cronometro;
Timer count;
int a = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cronometro);

    /**********************/
    boton_iniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    texto_cronometro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    count= new Timer("Contador");
    boton_iniciar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    a++;
                    texto_cronometro.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                }
            }, 100, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All action changing or touching UI objects should to run on Thread UI. 
Try:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cronometro);

    /**********************/
    boton_iniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    texto_cronometro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    count= new Timer("Contador");
    boton_iniciar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            count.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    a++;
                    ActivityCronometro.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {          
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        texto_cronometro.setText(String.valueOf(a));

                    }
                });

                }
            }, 100, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the user interface outside the ui thread.

Replace `texto_cronometro.setText(String.valueOf(a));` with this:

```
<youractivityname>.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        texto_cronometro.setText(String.valueOf(a));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To operate interface control in runnable.

reference code:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler( );

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable( ) {
 public void run ( )
 {
 atextview.setText(String.valueOf(a));
 handler.postDelayed(this,1000); //if continue Timer,use this sentence.
 }
 };
 handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000); // begin Timer
 handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); //stop Timer
```